# Java regex how to get value in brackets. Matcher does not work

Tags: java

I have a problem with matcher

```
String s = "termination:[2018-06-13T00:00:00 TO 2018-06-13T23:59:59]    "
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(".*(termination:\[(.+?) TO (.+?)\]?).*");
Matcher m = r.matcher(s);
if (m.find( )) {
    String startDate = m.group(2);
    String endDate = m.group(3);
}
```

But the end date is `2` instead of `2018-06-13T23:59:59`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

You have a slight typo in your regex. This is the corrected one:

```
.*(termination:\[(.+?) TO (.+?)\]).*
```

Your mistake is an extra `?` after `\]`. This makes the closing bracket optional, which in turn causes the lazy `(.+?)` to match only one character.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a more accurate pattern:

```
        String s = "termination:[2018-06-13T00:00:00 TO 2018-06-13T23:59:59]    ";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(".*(termination:\\[(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\sTO\\s(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\]?).*");
        Matcher m = r.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            String startDate = m.group(2);
            String endDate = m.group(3);
            System.out.println(startDate + " ---- " + endDate);
        }
```

... and it will print this:

```
2018-06-13T00:00:00 ---- 2018-06-13T23:59:59
```